# Error with loading datasource and convert it to json_data

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

I have a problem with converting datasource to json_data. Here is my code:

In my default.aspx.cs:

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetJson()
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

    DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable();

    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("EmpId", typeof(int));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    //
    // Here we add five DataRows.
    //
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(25, "Rk", "Gurgaon", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(50, "Sachin", "Noida", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(10, "Nitin", "Noida", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(21, "Aditya", "Meerut", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(100, "Mohan", "Banglore", DateTime.Now);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmployee.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dtEmployee.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

And here is in my default.apsx page:

```
var data2 = { };
    function GetJsonData(callback) {

        $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetJson",
                    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    //data: '{name:""}',
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        callback(msg);
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert('error');
                    }
                });
    }
    data2 = GetJsonData();
    $(function() {
        $("#MainTree,#SubTree").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "data": data2,
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "dnd"]
        });
    });
```

When I hide "data", ofcourse it won't create node. But now I want to call method GetJson from default.aspx.cs to get json_data from datasource. It always show "..Loading".. I'm using jsTree and just .net framework 2.0..Please help me to find out the solution for this..Thanks

Comment: Do you have any exception in cs?

Comment: Follow @AlexFilipovici post

Comment: @kostasch. no,I don't have any exception..

Comment: Try to return just  List<Dictionary<string, object>> and not string.

Comment: yup..i have changed and still got nothing..please see my editted code..I don't know why i return alert(error).

Answer (score 1):

Use `Default.aspx/GetJson` instead of `Default.aspx.cs/GetJson`.

Comment: oh..I have changed it and also add "static" for method..but it doesn't get any results..

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the filename(as @Alex Filipovici mentioned), your method needs to be `static`.

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetJson()
{
}
```

EDIT:::

This is what I did and got results back:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

            $("[id$=_btnPostReminder]").click(function () {
                var a = "";
                var remindertext = "";
                var re = "";
                var res = "";
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetJson",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:
        function Ret(response) {
            var Result = response.d
            alert(Result)

            return false;
        },
                    error: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                        alert(jqXHR);
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
```

Comment: I have tried and still get "..loading"..please see my edited code

Comment: can you step through GetJson method

Comment: I just copied your code above and uncommented this line:  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", and got success...

Comment: when i called ajax, it requested to server Default.aspx/GetJson (status code 200 OK), but i only receive message from error of ajax, after i check on network of browser i saw response page (html content) of page url which request